# Need help understanding Python Nested For Loop

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-loops

I'm having trouble understanding the 2nd for loop in the code below:

```
di = [4,5,6]
for i in range(len(di)):
    total = di[i]
    for j in range(i+1,len(di)):
        total += di[j]
        curr_di = total / ((j-i+1)**2)
```

I can't visualize what happens in `for j in range(i+1,len(di)):`, in particular the `i+1` portion confuses me. how does the i in the first loop affect the 2nd loop, if any?

Comment: it's a triangle double loop. It starts at the index of the first loop, which changes. Not sure what you don't understand. Try to print the values for small values of i,j

Comment: A simple `print`may shed some light on your problem

Comment: I don't understand why when I print(i) in the 2nd for loop, it returns `0
0
0
1
1
2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first loop is simply looping over the *indices* available in list `di`. For each entry in that loop, the second loop then examines the remaining portions of `di`.

So, on the first iteration, we're examining the value `4`. The second loop will then walk the list starting at that position, and running to the end (it will examine items `5` and `6`).

On the second iteration, we'll examine entry `5`, then walk the remainder of the list in the second loop (in this case `6`). Make sense?

As a commenter pointed out, print statements are your friend. Here's an example with some print statements to show how `i` and `j` change:

```
di = [4,5,6,7]
for i in range(len(di)):
  print(f"i: {i}")
  total = di[i]
  for j in range(i+1, len(di)):
    print(f" - j: {j}")
    total += di[j]
    curr_di = total / ((j-i+1)**2)
```

Output:

```
i: 0
 - j: 1
 - j: 2
 - j: 3
i: 1
 - j: 2
 - j: 3
i: 2
 - j: 3
i: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical "combinations of 2" loop.  Each item in the list (index i) is processed with every subsequent item (index j).

It looks like sequence processing to compute a sum of partial sums:

total = ∑*(i=1..n)* ( ∑*(j=i..n)* a[j] )